# How to select item (row) in ListView with Detail View Mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I make ListView with details view.

```
myListView.View = View.Details;
```

This ListView has 2 columns (date, title).

The item has a specific tag by which I can determine the database record for my needs.

How I can select one item (row in this Table) by click, get item's tag and make any action from my code (like a summon new form which show more details).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the [`FullRowSelect` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect)?

Comment: You can subscribe to the `ItemSelectionChanged`, verify whether `e.IsSelected = true` (since this (and other) event is raised both when an Item is selected and deselected), then check `e.Item` (and `e.Item.SubItems`, if required). Note that without `FullRowSelect`, you'll have to click on the first item on the list for the event(s) to raise. You may also prefer to keep `HoverSelection = false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
private void myListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myListView.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        switch (myListView.SelectedIndex.ToString())
        {
            ...

            case "2": //Details
            myListView.View = View.Details;

            ...
        }
    }

}
```